# flask-admin AdminIndexView error could not build url for endpoint '/admin.static' with values ['filename', 'v']. Did you mean 'admin.static' instead?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I want to customize flask-admin AdminIndexView's index view

```py
class CustomAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return super(CustomAdminIndexView, self).index()
    

admin = Admin(name=app_config["APP_NAME"], template_mode="bootstrap4", endpoint="/admin",index_view=CustomAdminIndexView())
```

[Following this code](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/auth-flask-login/app.py#L102)

It throws

```
BuildError
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/admin.static' with values ['filename', 'v']. Did you mean 'admin.static' instead?
```

I only want to customize the Index view of the admin panel.